# Possible to run OData on a shared host in mixed auth mode?

Tags: .net, odata, iis, authentication

My host has been pretty good about helping to tweak things to get my various .NET peices working, but they are unwilling to change the IIS authorization settings.  Presently my OData service whines about that.  Have I got any options?

Comment: You will need to be more specific. State both the imposed and the desired authentication scenarios.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you are actually asking a question about running WCF Data Services on a shared host?

Comment: Indeed I am trying to use WCF Data Services (as per the Data Service update referenced by this page http://blogs.msdn.com/astoriateam/archive/2010/01/27/data-services-update-for-net-3-5-sp1-available-for-download.aspx)

I assume they are running both anonymous and integrated authentication, based on the error message received (see below comments).  I presume I'll be needing anon only authentication, based on what I've read

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are hosting under IIS 7 you can add the following to your config file to disable an authentication method (basic, integrated, etc.).  I just went through this when hosting a WCF Data Service on a shared host and it was driving me crazy because they would let me turn it off, but any change to my site would cause it to enable again and I would start getting the error.

Hope this helps...

```
<system.webServer> 
     <security> 
            <authentication> 
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication> 
     </security> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I am going to give this a shot and I will post my results! thank you

Comment: Alas, this results in an error 500.  I bet they are running IIS6

Comment: For the record the error 500 appears no matter which page is browsed to, so it's not an exception within the service itself